# Syntax errors in Aptana when using Cake PHP

Tags: syntax-error, cakephp-3.0, aptana3

I've installed **Aptana Studio 3** on my **Mac** and want to use **CakePHP**. The installation of **CakePHP (Version: 3.3.6)** was successful but I'm getting syntax errors in **Aptana**.

The **PHP** Version in **Aptana** for my project is "**PHP 5.4.x**", the highest version what I can select in Project/Properties/PHP Development -> Compatibility, PHP Version.

According to the installation book of Cake, PHP 5.5.9 or higher is required (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html).

How can I update my Aptana Studio to use the required PHP version? Or is there another reason for the syntax errors?

e.g. syntax error in **AppController.php.ctp:**

[image]

[image]

I'm using Aptana build: 3.6.1.201410201044

Comment: You may want to just use eclipse. Aptana has a plugin version 4.3.1 on the marketplace. Or just use the PHP version.

Comment: My solution was to use Netbeans 8.1.
That's weird that Aptana is not supporting a higher PHP version.

Comment: Yeah .. i am having issues with Aptana in the latest eclipse (Neon2) as well and stopped installing it. I also use Atom and that goes pretty well.